# ServiceProcessInstaller fails with "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done"

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, installation

I have an installer class using `ServiceProcessInstaller`. In the installer class in the constructor I add it to installers:

```
serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

// Add Both Installers to Project Installers Collection to be Run
Installers.AddRange(new Installer[]
                                {
                                    serviceProcessInstaller,
                                    serviceInstaller
                                });
```

and in Install method I set the username and password:

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    .... open the form, bla bla bla
    serviceProcessInstaller.Password = accountForm.txtPassword.Text;
    serviceProcessInstaller.Username = accountForm.txtServiceAccount.Text;
    serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
}
```

when I try to run it however, I get the very descriptive error message: "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done". What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I tested that this error happens only when I install this component using msi package. It works just fine when I run InstallUtil against it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it finally: there seems to be a "feature" in `ServiceProcessInstaller`, where the code overwrites the values I provided explicitly with the values from the context. The MSI installer set the username to some crap (my company name), and `ServiceProcessInstaller` tried to install the service as this user and not the one explicitly provided by me. So the workaround is to set the correct values in the config:

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    .... open the form, bla bla bla
    serviceProcessInstaller.Password = accountForm.txtPassword.Text;
    Context.Parameters["PASSWORD"] = accountForm.txtPassword.Text;
    serviceProcessInstaller.Username = accountForm.txtServiceAccount.Text;
    Context.Parameters["USERNAME"] = accountForm.txtServiceAccount.Text;
    serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I have exactly the same problem but the approach above makes no difference to me. I'm using VS2010/NET4 and I'm wondering whether MS have changed something here - I'm working with code that worked under previous versions of .NET.

Comment: Isn't there a typo here - mixing up the USERNAME and the PASSWORD parameters? Or is it a quirk?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its got something to do with your service account on you machine environment

- http://www.shog9.com/log/archives/1-No-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-IDs-was-done.html
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890737
- http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/227254-serviceprocessinstaller-account-user-doesnt-work

Hope the help to understand your situation.

Comment: Sorry, checked that. The problem seems to be only when I run it from the msi, it works fine when I use InstallUtil -> so the parameters are fine

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for ages, trying to run a user service with my own account. The problem turned out to be that I had no password on my account. Once I put a password on it worked straight away

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the username from `user` to `.\user` to signify it is on the local machine.