# Can't get user service to work in vs 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I'm trying to create a windows user service, I've been skipping over this problem for a few weeks because I could get it going as a local service. I'm using `vs2010` ultimate.

When I go to install it whether I provide credentials in the box provided or through code, I get the below error

```
Error 1001: no mapping between account names and security ids was done
```

Ive done a lot of searching and to be honest I just don't understand whats going on, the error seems to be pretty common.
My understanding is that Im creating a user here (as opposed to running as an existing user) but open to correction?

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = "MyPC\\UserName"; // or "UserName";
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = "password123";
```

I'm hoping this is something simple im doing wrong but cant find a solution...

Does anyone know how to get this working..?

Comment: Very similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643287/serviceprocessinstaller-fails-with-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-securit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Windows Service - No mapping between account names and security ID's were done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375622/installing-windows-service-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids)

Comment: Indeed they are similar but I haven't found a working solution from these questions.. One marked answer says to use a local service which is hardly a solution! the other solution says to set the values in the config - i dont know how to do this..